# Is it possible to play a video in Flutter backwards?

Tags: flutter

I'm using `video_player` plugin and can't find an option to play a video backwards.
Is there a different plugin with that functionality?

Specifically, I'm trying to create a video loop, where the video plays forward and then backwards

Comment: not sure if there is a plugin for that  but i think you can get the video frames as a list and reverse it [this](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame) package might help